# Making bountied questions more visible

Tags: feature-request, bounty

When questions are bountied you lose score and for some people with lower scores this can be problematic. You should expect to see huge benefits from the bounties however, they are not very clear. I think you should get a notification when you log onto the website or something about bountied questions as for phone users you have to choose a filter and even on PC it isnt too noticeable.

Comment: This sounds like a feature-request. You should ask this on [meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) on a beta site none is really able to do something about that.

Answer (score 2):

Bountied questions have their own tab on both the homepage and the [main question list](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions). There aren't any bountied questions right now, but this is how it should look like:

[image: homepage]
(homepage)

[image: question list]
(question list)

Also, bountying a question makes it active again and bumps it to the front page.

Comment: I know they have their own tabs but even so for mobile users it isnt really all that useful and for pc users it doesnt really attract too much attention. Bountied questions get as much views as normal questions do (almost as much) it doesnt really seem to be fair especially considering you are giving 50 score for it.